# php mail function and if condition

Tags: php, email

I am trying to use the mail function in PHP. On one page I have this form:

```
<form action="sending.php" method="POST">
subject of the e-mail: <input type="text" name="subject" size="40" /><br>
recipient's e-mail: <input type="text" name="to" size="40" />
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send" />
</form>
```

which points to this other page. The if condition doesn't work. The output returns a positive message even if I leave the fields of the form empty.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["to"], $_POST["subject"]))
{
$to=$_POST["to"];
$subject=$_POST["subject"];;
$message='hello';
mail($to, $subject, $message);
echo "The data have been sent to the e-mail address you typed in.";
}
else
{
echo "I think you forgot to type in an e-mail address and/or a subject.";
}
?>
```

Can you suggest how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You need to test that they're not set to `==`, not just whether they're set.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the `length` of the strings that are being posted via http.

In the case of a string that needs to have e-mail format, you may need to perform a more sophisticated check. It is not hard to find some functions to validate emails in form both in javascript and PHP, look for some and use the one that fits the most to your skills/code :)

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` is true if the variable is set to the empty string. You can use `empty()` instead

```
if (!empty($_POST['to']) && !empty($_POST['subject']))
```

Answer (score 0):

If in input element has a `name` is it is always passed to the `action` page. You should check like so.

```
if($_POST['subject'] != "" && $_POST['to'] != ""){
    //send message
}else{
    //dont send message
}
```

Comment: Yes. I definitely need to check that email addresses are valid. I am also a bit concerned about spammers who might take advantage of this mail() function. Thanks!

Comment: To check if the address are valid use regex. See `preg_match` function for that. As far as spammers taking advantage of your website, there is not an easy way to do this. I am not an expert on security but I imagine you could limit emails by IP address in some manner.